# How to map tangent vectors on the hyperboloid to corresponding tangent vectors on the Poincaré ball

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Every point on the hyperboliod is mapped via the stereographic projection to the Poincaré ball.

Now, how does one map tangent vectors on the hyperboloid to tangent vectors on the Poincaré ball?

One approach that I thought about was to use the same stereographic projection. However, what I‘m not sure about is whether the stereographically projected tangent vectors on the hyperplane, where the Poincaré ball lies, are of the correct scale. Certainly, they will point in the right direction.

What is a principled approach to map tangent vectors from one manifold to another manifold if there exists an isometry between them (which in this case is the stereographic projection)?

---

## Stereographic Projection

Let $R$ be the radius of the $n$-dimensional hyperboloid, and $K$ be the sectional curvature. Then we have $R=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|K|}}$. The the formula for the stereographic projection is:

$$
\begin{align*}
\text{sproj}\colon&&\mathbb{R}^{n+1}&\to\mathbb{R}^{n}
\\
&&
(x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1})
&\mapsto
\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{|K|}x_{n+1}}
(x_1,\ldots,x_n)
\end{align*}
$$

---

## Differential of Stereographic Projection

$$
D_{\text{sproj}}(x)
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{|K|}x_{n+1}}
\mathbf{I}
&
\frac{\sqrt{|K|}}{(1-\sqrt{|K|}x_{n+1})^2}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
\vdots\\
x_n\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

---

## Mapping of Tangent Vectors

Putting everything together we get the mapping that maps tangent vectors on the hyperboloid to tangent vectors on the Poincaré ball.

$$
\mathbf{v}
\mapsto
D_{\text{sproj}}(x)\mathbf{v}
$$

---

Is that correct?

Comment: That's why smooth mappings have derivatives!!

Comment: @TedShifrin How does that relate to the question?

Comment: Because the derivative maps tangent vectors to tangent vectors?

Comment: Thanks! I didn‘t know about that. So you mean the derivative of the stereographic projection?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks! I got you now! Took me a while The stereographic projection gives the point on the Poincaré ball as a function $f$ of the point on the hyperboloid. The derivative of $f$ gives the tangent vector on the Poincaré ball as a function of the point on the hyperboloid and a tangent vector at that point.

Comment: @TedShifrin Is my current proposal correct?

Comment: Yes, sure, it looks fine. Of course, you're going to apply the derivative mapping only to tangent vectors of the hyperboloid at a given point.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks!